# How to have Cytoscape recognize an edge column as a weight for layout

Tags: cytoscape

I am a relatively new user of Cytoscape. I am trying to have my layout take an edge column attribute into account. The edge column is a weight. When I hover over any of the layouts that incorporate edge attributes (e.g., prefuse force directed, edge weight spring embedded), the only edge column that appears is EdgeBetweenness. I went to Layout > Settings and clicked on "Edge column that contains the weights:", and only EdgeBetweenness is listed. Any suggestions for how I can have my column (which is called, uncreatively, "weight") be recognized as a weight for layout purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that your edge column was imported as a string for some reason.  You need to force it to import as a double in order to be able to use it as a weight.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks Scooter. Is it possible to change the column's data type after the data has already been imported? Or can the data type only be specified when it is first being imported into the software?